# deploying a war file with maven to tomcat using HTTPS

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, https

I'm using Tomcat 8, Maven 3.1.1 , JDK 1.8.0_31 and tomcat7-maven-plugin 2.2 .
My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

I can't deploy a war file to Tomcat when it's configured for HTTPS. HTTP works fine.

I found two threads on Stackoverflow but they didn't solve my problem.

The keystore file contains only one entry.
My maven settings.xml contains valid admin credentials for the tomcat server.

Here is the POM plugin configuration.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>https://localhost:8443/manager/text</url>
                <server>tomcat8-local</server>
                <path>/entryServlet</path>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>D:\intellij-project\keystore\keystore</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>pass1</keystorePass>
            </configuration>
        </pugin>
```

This is the maven output:

```
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ intellij-project ---
[INFO] Deploying war to https://localhost:8443/entryServlet  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.194s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 21 10:13:29 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) on project intellij-project:
Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The problem is not https, the problem is that the https requires mutual authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: I had to import my self-created certificate in 
the Java keystore located in JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security

I followed these instructions:
[No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)

Comment: please help....followed instructions there and still getting the error....